# Hooks can only be called inside of the body of function component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, node-modules

I'm going crazy.
The UI was working perfectly, and at some point, I didn't even change anything, it started giving me this error.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

```
    332 | export default function MiniDrawer() {
  > 333 |   const classes = useStyles();
    334 |   const theme = useTheme();
    335 |   const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    336 |   const [tabValue, setValue] = React.useState(0);
```

I've been trying to restore files to previous versions, but I still get that error.

Comment: Your sample code seems fine.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#:~:text=Hooks%20can%20only%20be%20called,of%20React%20and%20React%20DOM.&text=You%20might%20have%20more%20than,React%20in%20the%20same%20app.

Comment: Read the article.
Version is fine

Comment: Does it work if you declare the function then `export default MiniDrawer`? Might be a problem with the way it's bundled. I seem to remember having some difficulties with combining those lines into one line.

Comment: Ok I solved, apparently I had a problem with having multiple React instances, although I can't figure out how it happened as I litterally didn't touch any code.